# Memory allocation of Integers

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Let's say I have a UInt16 made up of 2 UInt8s (upper bits and lower bits)

Is this statement correct?

> As long as the value of the UInt16 is less than 256, all of the memory will exist in the lower bits and the upper bits will be 0

Comment: "all of the memory will exist in the lower bits" is not a very meaningful phrase.

Comment: This statement is awkward. The binary representation of unsigned integers is guaranteed to be the canonical binary encoding. So yes, one can claim that the upper 8 bits of a 16 bit integer less than 256 will be zeroes.

Comment: A `uint16_t` is not "made up of 2 [`uint8_t`s]". Those are separate types. All objects' representations can be thought of as being made up of `[[un]signed] char`s. Is that what you meant? `uint8_t` need not be compatible with the `char` types (or share their special aliasing abilities or etc.)

Comment: @underscore_d - `char` is also a separate type :/

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, I tend to write `[[un]signed] char` in an attempt to concisely indicate that these are 3 distinct types, though it's probably not very clear to anyone except me!

Comment: @underscore_d - I understand that, I'm just pointing out that your phrasing "those are separate types" also applies to `char`, etc.  So you may want to clarify what the distinction is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the set bits will be in the lower byte when the value is treated as a 16-bit unit, however if you cast the address of your variable to a char * you may find that the 'low byte' precedes the 'high byte' in memory.

This is called little-endian storage and is true, for example, on intel x86 based processors.